# Assigning to a char * const * variable from a char * * variable - why is it allowed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am surprised that the following behavior of C++ (Visual Studio 2012 compiler).

```
char * * PointerToPointerToChar = NULL;
char * const * PointerToConstPointerToChar = NULL;
char const * * PointerToPointerToConstChar = NULL;

PointerToPointerToConstChar = PointerToPointerToChar; // Assignment 1: Gives compiler error as I would expect
PointerToConstPointerToChar = PointerToPointerToChar; // Assignment 2: NO COMPILER ERROR ???

PointerToPointerToChar = PointerToPointerToConstChar; // Assignment 3: Gives compiler error as I would expect
PointerToPointerToChar = PointerToConstPointerToChar; // Assignment 4: Gives compiler error as I would expect
```

I understand the const keyword in C++, specifically how it's placement affects what is considered const (the entity to the left).

It seems like the compiler tries to protect the user of the RHS variable from a const-stripping alias *at either level of indirection* (assignments 3 and 4).  But the LHS is only protected from a const-stripping alias at one level of indirection (assignment 1) and not the other level of indirection (assignment 2).  In other words, given that the following is prevented by the compiler

```
PointerToPointerToConstChar = PointerToPointerToChar; // Assignment 1: Gives compiler error as I would expect
PointerToPointerToChar[0][0] = 'A'; // The user of the LHS variable was effectively lied to about the constness of the *characters* - second level of indirection
```

then why isn't the following also prevented by the compiler

```
PointerToConstPointerToChar = PointerToPointerToChar; // Assignment 2: NO COMPILER ERROR ???
PointerToPointerToChar[0] = NULL; // The user of the LHS variable was effectively lied to about the constness of the *pointers* - first level of indirection
```

Is this correct C++, and if so what is the rationale?  It seems inconsistent.  Thanks!

Comment: Let's ask about the simple case first: do you understand why `int *pi; const int *pci; int i = 1; pi = &i; pci = pi; ++*pi;` is okay even though `*pci` changes? If not, you may want to ask about that instead. If you do, can you highlight the difference you see between that and your example?

Comment: The case with only one level of indirection doesn't seem inconsistent in any way to me, since there is only one level of indirection.  It is only when there is two levels of indirection that it seems inconsistent to me.  Because  in that case, having the const on the variable on the LHS of the assignment apply to the _second_ level of indirection gives a compiler error, but having the const apply to the _first_ level of indirection does not.  In both cases the LHS is *more* "consty" than the RHS but in one case it is not allowed.

Comment: So instead of an explanation of why `char**` can be implicitly converted to `char*const*`, would an explanation of why the conversion from `char**` to `const char**` is unsafe also suffice? (Actually, I see that Fireho and R Sahu already included explanations on that in their answers.)

Comment: Thanks, like you said the answers below enlightened me.  For me the key to understand this was the introduction of a third variable that was `char const *` (`const char str[]` in Fireho's answer) - the disallowed assignment facilitates a violation of constness of that variable, even though it was only ever directly assigned to other variables that were also const at the `char` level.  So C++ must disallow the assignment/implicit type conversion that faciliates that.  The allowed assignment doesn't faciliate anything similar.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type const*` doesn't mean the value won't change, it means you can't change it using that pointer.

---

Because if you could do that, you could assign to the `*PointerToPointerToConstChar` any `const char*` - while `PointerToPointerToChar` relies on it being normal `char*`. If that was allowed:

```
PointerToPointerToConstChar = PointerToPointerToChar; // assume PointerToPointerToChar is pointing to a valid memory block
const char str[] = "Hello world!";
*PointerToPointerToConstChar = str;
(*PointerToPointerToChar)[0] = 'X'; // Oops, we just modified a const array
```

Comment: I fully understand that.  My question boils down to why is Assignement 1 not allowed, but Assignment 2 is allowed?  In both cases, a pointer with const at one level of indirection is assigned a pointer with no constness whatsoever.  I wouldn't be confused if _both_ were allowed, and I also wouldn't be confused if _neither_ were allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now!  `str[]` never had his constness cast away but was still screwed :).  Nothing similar can if the const is at the other level of indirection (`char * const *`).  What also helped me was testing what assignments were allowed with _three_ levels of indirection.  The same problem can happen if C++ allowed `PtrToPtrToPtrToConstChar = PtrToPtrToPtrToChar` and also if C++ allowed `PtrToPtrToConstPtrToChar = PtrToPtrToPtrToChar`...and sure enough neither of these is allowed.  Just `PtrToConstPtrToPtrToChar = PtrToPtrToPtrToChar` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a `char**` to a `char* const*` is analogous to assigning a `char*` to a `const char*`. It makes perfect sense.

```
char array[] = "foo";
char* ptr1 = array;            // Can change array through ptr1
char const* ptr2 = ptr1;       // Can't change array through ptr2
```

Use of `char**` and `char* const*` complicates what can and what can't be changed a bit more.

```
char** ptrptr1 = &ptr1;

// Can change where ptr1 points to through ptrptr1
*ptrptr1 = <some other char*>; // OK

// Can change the value of what ptr1 points to through ptrptr1.
(*ptrptr1)[0] = 'x';           // OK

char* const* ptrptr2 = ptr1;

// Can't change where ptr1 points to through ptrptr2
*ptrptr2 = <some other char*>; // Not OK

// Can change the value of what ptr1 points to through ptrptr2.
// (*ptrptr2) is still of type 'char*'.
(*ptrptr2)[0] = 'x';           // OK
```

Comment: Assigning a `char**` to a ``char* const*`` is Assignment 2 above.  But why is Assignment 1 treated differently?  That is: `char * * ptrptr1 = Initialize();  const * * ptrptr2 = ptrptr1`.  This seems like the same thing, I just can't use `ptrptr2` to change the character data e.g. `ptrptr2[0][0] = 'a'`.  But, the assignment `const * * ptrptr2 = ptrptr1` is not allowed.

Comment: @DaveStone, I added some more info to the answer. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Pointer to something that is `const`. The pointer is not `const`, just what it points to. You assign to that pointer a pointer to something that is not `const`. That is fine. The pointer is not const and the `const` in this case just tells us, that the object pointed to will not be changed **through this pointer**. It doesn't have to be const anywhere else.

```
char* c = someCharPointerSomewhere;
PointerToConstPointerToChar = PointerToPointerToChar;
*PointerToConstPointerToChar = c // const violation
*PointerToPointerToChar = c // this is fine
// now *PointerToConstPointerToChar will be c as well.
```

Then why can you not assign to a pointer to a pointer to `const`? Well, the pointer to `const` is a different type than a pointer to non `const`. The implicit conversion we have above does not apply in this case. You could use this pointer to let the pointer it points to point to something, that actually is `const`. Then the original pointer would allow to modify the const value indirectly.

```
const char c = 'c';
PointerToPointerToConstChar = PointerToPointerToChar;
*PointerToPointerToConstChar = c;
**PointerToPointerToChar = 'a'; // const violation!
```

It is a bit confusing, when you just read the explanations, but take your time and think it through. It really is logically consistent that way.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense...for whatever reason I didn't understand your answer initially but now it is clear to me.  It boils down to introducing a third variable (`const char c` in your second code chunk above) that, if the disallowed assignment/conversion were actually allowed in C++, would get const-violated even though it was never directly abused via a `<const_cast>` or whatever.  Like you said, kind of confusing and something I just didn't "get" until I finally  "got" it.